# MySQL: Join Conditions based on a Table on a later Join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    p.Sku,
    p.Barcode,
    s.AmountIncl,

    CASE
        WHEN SUM(dl.Qty) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(dl.Qty)
    END AS Qty,

    CASE
        WHEN SUM(dl.SubTotal) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(dl.SubTotal)
    END AS SubTotal

FROM
    Product AS p

        LEFT JOIN
    DocumentLine AS dl ON p.Sku = dl.Sku

        LEFT JOIN
    Document AS d ON dl.DocumentId = d.DocumentId
        AND d.DocumentTypeEnum = 'Order'
        AND d.PaymentStatusEnum = 'Paid'

        LEFT JOIN
    StandardPrice AS s ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId

WHERE
    p.Barcode IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY p.Sku
```

I'm trying to get Qty and SubTotal figures grouped by Sku for Orders that have actually been paid.
These orders can be identified in the Document table with the conditions (d.DocumentTypeEnum = 'Order' & d.PaymentStatusEnum = 'Paid').
The financial data (Qty & SubTotal) live in DocumentLine.

How do I exclude orders/data in the DocumentLine table that are linked to a Document (linked via DocumentId) where DocumentTypeEnum IS NOT an 'Order', and the PaymentStatusEnum IS NOT 'Paid' ?

At this moment the DocumentLine includes Paid Orders, Failed Orders, Unpaid Orders, Pending Orders, Carts, etc. So the Qty and SubTotal data is way higher than we actually have sold/generated.

NOTE: I still want to show all Sku WHERE Barcode IS NOT NULL. So if there is no date in DocumentLine for a Sku the Qty and SubTotal values should be 0 ?

I'm querying in MySQL

Sample Data

```
Product
Sku | Barcode
1   | A
2   | B
3   | 
4   | C
5   |
6   | D

DocumentLine
Sku | Qty | SubTotal | DocumentId
1   | 1   | 100      | 123
2   | 1   | 150      | 124
4   | 2   | 400      | 125
6   | 1   | 120      | 128
1   | 2   | 200      | 129
4   | 1   | 200      | 131
3   | 1   | 600      | 127

Document
DocumentId | DocumentTypeEnum | PaymentStatusEnum
123        | Order            | Paid
124        | Cart             | NotApplicable
125        | Order            | Pending
126        | Cart             | NotApplicable
127        | Cart             | NotApplicable
128        | Order            | Failed
129        | Order            | Paid
130        | Cart             | NotApplicable
131        | Order            | Paid

Result:
Sku | Barcode | AmountIncl | Qty | SubTotal
1   | A       | 50         | 3   | 300
2   | B       | 60         | 0   | 0
4   | C       | 40         | 1   | 200
6   | D       | 80         | 0   | 0
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ? that really help

Comment: Question statement looks little confusing. You want qty and subtotal for the orders that are paid at the same time you also want to exclude the order with PaymentStatusEnum as "Paid". Can you please make it more clear.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: @D-Shih Added sample data

Comment: @PoorviNigotiya I want to exclude everything that IS NOT an Order and that IS NOT paid. Made the question a bit more clear now

Comment: Why will your `Barcode = B` and`Barcode = D` `Qty = 0`? there are some row in `Document` table

Comment: @jarlh Better like this?

Comment: @D-Shih Because the DocumentTypeEnum and PaymentStatusEnum in the DocumentLine rows linked to the Document rows are NOT 'Order' AND 'Paid'

Comment: Looks much better now!

Comment: @MichielvanDijk I write an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT p.Sku, p.Barcode, s.AmountIncl, 
                CASE WHEN SUM(doc.Qty) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE SUM(doc.Qty)
            END AS Qty,
            CASE WHEN SUM(doc.SubTotal) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE SUM(doc.SubTotal)
            END AS SubTotal
        FROM Product AS p
           LEFT JOIN (Select dl.sku as sku, dl.qty as qty, dl.subtotal as subtotal 
               from DocumentLine dl, Document d where dl.DocumentId = d.DocumentId
              AND d.DocumentTypeEnum = 'Order' AND d.PaymentStatusEnum = 'Paid') AS doc 
              ON p.Sku = doc.Sku
           LEFT JOIN StandardPrice AS s ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId

        WHERE p.Barcode IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.Sku
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. just use `LEFT JOIN` base on `Product` table and filter `Barcode` which you want to get. with condition aggregate function to make it.

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
   Sku INT,
   Barcode VARCHAR(10)
);



INSERT INTO Product VALUES (1,'A');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES (2,'B');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES (3,'');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES (4,'C');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES (5,'');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES (6,'D');


CREATE TABLE DocumentLine(
   Sku INT,
   Qty INT,
  SubTotal INT,
  DocumentId INT
);



INSERT INTO DocumentLine VALUES (1, 1, 100,123);
INSERT INTO DocumentLine VALUES (2, 1, 150,124);
INSERT INTO DocumentLine VALUES (4, 2, 400,125);
INSERT INTO DocumentLine VALUES (6, 1, 120,128);
INSERT INTO DocumentLine VALUES (1, 2, 200,129);
INSERT INTO DocumentLine VALUES (4, 1, 200,131);
INSERT INTO DocumentLine VALUES (3, 1, 600,127);


CREATE TABLE Document(
   Sku INT,
   DocumentTypeEnum VARCHAR(50),
  PaymentStatusEnum VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Document VALUES (123 ,'Order',  'Paid');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (124 ,'Cart',  'NotApplicable');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (125 ,'Order',  'Pending');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (126 ,'Cart',  'NotApplicable');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (127 ,'Cart',  'NotApplicable');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (128 ,'Order',  'Failed');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (129 ,'Order',  'Paid');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (130 ,'Cart',  'NotApplicable');
INSERT INTO Document VALUES (131 ,'Order',  'Paid');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  p.sku,
  Barcode,
  SUM(case when DocumentTypeEnum = 'Order' and PaymentStatusEnum = 'Paid' then Qty  else 0 end) 'Qty',
  SUM(case when DocumentTypeEnum = 'Order' and PaymentStatusEnum = 'Paid' then SubTotal  else 0 end) 'SubTotal'  
from product p 
left join DocumentLine dl on dl.sku = p.sku
left join Document d on dl.DocumentId = d.Sku
WHERE Barcode <> '' OR Barcode IS NOT NULL
group by p.sku,Barcode
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/173760/7/0)**:

```
| sku | Barcode | Qty | SubTotal |
|-----|---------|-----|----------|
|   1 |       A |   3 |      300 |
|   2 |       B |   0 |        0 |
|   4 |       C |   1 |      200 |
|   6 |       D |   0 |        0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want  the document there are not Order and Paid  use   an INNER JOIN for Document and not left  join

```
SELECT p.Sku
  , p.Barcode
  , s.AmountIncl
  , CASE WHEN SUM(dl.Qty) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(dl.Qty)
    END AS Qty
  , CASE WHEN SUM(dl.SubTotal) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(dl.SubTotal)
    END AS SubTotal
FROM Product AS p
LEFT JOIN DocumentLine AS dl ON p.Sku = dl.Sku
INNER JOIN Document AS d ON dl.DocumentId = d.DocumentId
    AND d.DocumentTypeEnum = 'Order'
      AND d.PaymentStatusEnum = 'Paid'
LEFT JOIN StandardPrice AS s ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId
WHERE p.Barcode IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY p.Sku
```

Comment: I've tried that, and it returned the correct data. However, I also want to see Skus that have no sales data (they should display a value of 0 for Qty and SubTotal)

Comment: update your question and show me the exact result (coherent with your sample) you have using my code  ..

Comment: seems you change the question stesp by step  .. i think my answer was correct for your original question  ..   ..  .

Comment: I didn't. Question has been the same since the first version. Just added some data and clarification for those who needed that

Comment: Is not clear if the result is what you need  or is what  you get with my code  .. i need both for understand what you are looking for